# Google api Java client: access token expiration

Tags: google-api-java-client

I am using the Java sdk for getting user and group data in a server to server flow and everything works OK.

The SDK nicely hides all the OAuth complexity and the `request.execute()` method makes a first HTTP call to get the OAuth token and a second call to the actual API for getting user and group data.

I have some doubts around how the SDK handles the calls to the OAuth endpoint

1. Does the `request.execute()` method always calls the OAuth endpoint?
2. If not how often?
3. Is the access token "cached" by the SDK?
4. Does the SDK manage the token expiration properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GoogleCredential` "does the right things" for token refreshing.

1. No. It caches the token and reuses it.
2. The token returned from the server has an expiration time. The token can be reused as long as it hasn't expired.
3. Yes, but only in-memory, unless using something like the FileDataStoreFactory
4. Yes. It caches the token until it is about to expire, and refreshes it pro-actively, generally before getting an authentication error from the server.